# Parse List of Entities using Json In Javascript + MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have looked for a solution , but nothing that fits my needs was found on the site, so here goes:

I have a Controller that returns a Json:

```
  return Json(new { Item = searchModule});
```

searchModule is a list of Profiles:

```
{ "Item":[{"ProfileID":4854,"NickName":"Johnny","users":null,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}]}
```

In JavaScript we have:

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: action/controller,
         data: "{queryString:'" + searchVal + "'}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
         alert(data.Item)
         }
     })
```

That returns an object. How can I obtain: Firstname,LastName and NickName ???

Additional answer: If I write the code like below:

```
var request = $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: action/controller,
             data: "{queryString:'" + searchVal + "'}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
}
         }).responseText
var obj = json.Parse(request)
```

, request is null.

Comment: fyi... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990710/javascript-mvc-controller-caling-and-return-parameters/9990836#9990836

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since they're objects structured according to the JSON, you should be able to just access the properties like so: `data.Item[0].Firstname`. You *may or may not* need to use [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to get to this step - calling that is trivial.

Comment: Thanks.Works fine.Tried it 2 hours ago, apparently my process needed to be killed . data.Item[0].Firstname worked fine .